# header .h file not found error in Xcode 7

Tags: file, header, xcode7

I am working on a project which includes CLucene library. It Builds and runs fine on Xcode 6 but after upgrading to Xcode 7 it gives an error -Clucene/stdHeader.h file not found. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: have you verified that the include folder is set in the project properties ?

Comment: yes, I am able to see the files in Project properties->general-> linked frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it

Select the project in the navigation panel and select target to TechEFB, Then switch to "Build Settings" tab.
Goto "Search paths” -> “User Header Search Paths"
Double click the value and add the following paths of the library or file:
/Users/Lax/Documents/MyProj/subfolder/Libraries/Clucene/include/shared
/Users/Lax/Documents/MyProj/subfolder/Libraries/Clucene/include/core

NOTE: this is an absolute path. You will need to change the first part to find where your Xcode project is and replace the path.

In the same page, click on ALL option, search for “Bitcode”. Xcode will filter the options for you.
Set “Enable Bitcode” to NO

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in react-native. Was trying to add Crashlytics to my application following this [crashlytics-tutorial](https://medium.com/delivery-com-engineering/add-crashlytics-to-your-react-native-ios-app-69a983a9062a) and ended up failing the build due to RCTLog.h not found.
Using Lax's solution I also ended up in "Header Search Paths" and added the following search path

> $(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React/Base

Then it was able to build!